# Error using 'path' for collection: in simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple_form_for. In that I want a drop down with few values. These values are returned from a method in the controller which returns a hash of those values.

In the view I have:

```
= f.input :address_id, collection: address_string_gift_cards_path
```

The controller method is:

```
def address_string
  #Some code here that returns hash of values
end
```

In my routes file I have:

```
resources :gift_cards do
    collection do
      get :address_string
    end
  end
```

In the output I am getting error:

```
undefined method `to_a' for "/gift_cards/address_string":String
```

I dont know what mistake I am making. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Can you post your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection:` expects an array of objects. It transforms those objects into selectable options.

You're giving it a String - the path to a controller method that would return the values. So you're expecting it to "go there and fetch these values for me", but that's not something simple_form_for knows how to do.

Instead, you need to hand the data to `collection:` directly. You can declare `address_string` in your controller to be a helper method:

```
class GiftCardsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :address_string

  def address_string
    ..
  end
end
```

Helper methods can be called directly from the view:

```
= f.input :address_id, collection: address_string
```

More info on `collection:` is available at https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections.

Comment: I understood what mistake I was making. Thnx for your help:)